# how to send csv file to download using NodeJS and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js

In my server side i'm generating csv file with some data.when user click on `download` button i want to send this csv and download it on user's browser.

**server script Node.js**

```
 exports.downCsv = (req, res) => {

            var file =req.query.csvUrl;
            res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname +'/../../'+config.tempCsvDir+'/'+file));

    };
```

**Client side AngularJS**

```
 var downCSV=function(url){

    Common.get('api/reports/downCsv?csvUrl='+url+'',
    {},function (get_data){

      if(get_data){

          console.log("",get_data);
      }else{
          console.log("error",get_data.message);
      }
    });

  };
```

when i click `download` button,`console.log` showing data inside of csv file.but i want user to download it.

Comment: but i want to send my csv file from server side to client. when i use `<a href="" ` or what ever url reference in client side.then client will know my server path.thats why iwa nt to send my csv to client.not generated csv file url.

Comment: You can simply add the file under static folder of your node app (Similar to js and css file, some other file say media/assets). and that link will download the file for sure. I had similar requirement few days ago and I have done that and it had worked fine for me.